# How to get java file path to source file in a system independent way?

Tags: java, directory, path, relative-path, absolute-path

So I need to read from a .csv file, finding the right filepath to do it. In my code I just currently have all my .java and .class files in the same folder as my .csv files, however I must set it up in a certain way that I'm not sure how to do.

All my .java and .class files will be contained in a directory labeled

```
studentname/assesment1/src/
```

And the .csv files will be contained in a directory labeled

```
studentname/assesment1/res/
```

How would I get an absolute path to the .java and .class files in the src directory and then use relative paths to get to the res directory in a platform independent way?

Some graders will use windows machines and others will use mac machines. I am not told where the "studentname" directory is going to be held in relation to anything else.

Any help?

Comment: Are you the teacher or a student?

Comment: I am a student. (To clarify- the assignment isn't about file entry, it's about using java objects. We're allowed to hardcode the csv data into our program, I just wanted to learn how to do the file handling to learn better practices)